# unzipping multiple files at once

Tags: multi-core, unzip

I have thousands of .zip files in one folder, I want to extract those using command or script, each .zip file to it own folder.
I wish to run the unzip process multiple times.
How can i do that?

Comment: @Siraj this question is about multiple ZIP files at a time, not about ZIP files within ZIP files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick, run this on terminal

```
for f in *.zip; do unzip $f -d ${f%.*}; done
```

Ok redefined answer taking into consideration the comment:

In one file named unzip.sh put this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
LEN=${#}
COUNT=0
PROCESSES=20
ITERATE=$(( LEN/PROCESSES ))
for ((i=0;i<=ITERATE;i++))
do 
    LOWER=$(( i*PROCESSES+1 ))
    HIGHER=$(( (i+1)*PROCESSES ))
    ./aux.sh ${@:$LOWER:$HIGHER} &!
done
```

In one file named aux.sh put this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $@; do unzip $f -d ${f%.*}; done
```

Remember to set both files with executions permissions by typing in the terminal: `chmod +x unzip.sh aux.sh` 
Now all you have to do is executing the script by typing in the terminal: `./unzip.sh *.zip`

Comment: Thank you, but i wish to run the unzip process several times because there are thousands of .zip files.

Comment: You want to unzip some zips each time and running the script several times until you made it? If so, can the zips already unzipped be deleted?

Comment: I want to extract zip files, in order to accomplish it in a short time i wish to run the unzip process itself several times (parallel), each zip to its own folder.

Comment: Ok i think I can do a little script for you to run if you're interest, I'll post as another answer

Comment: Thank you @Diogo Vilela, will it extract each zip file in its own folder?

Comment: Yes, if it helped pls upvote :-)

Comment: This answer appeared to work -- however, it also appears to hang the Terminal, i.e. it is not returning to the command prompt for a new command to be executed in Terminal. My only recourse is to close the Terminal and open a new one. What is missing from this code that would "finish" the shell(?) script and return to the command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

`xargs` with `-P n` can be used to run a program in parallel for multiple files. The following, for example, runs 8 instances of `unzip` in parallel.

```
cd directory-with-zip-files
find . -name '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 8 unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files inside the zip files are in their respective folders, an easier solution would be to type this in the opened terminal of the zip files' folder:

> unzip "*.zip"

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this, and decided to try [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sphinx.html). Here is how you do it with parallel:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' |  parallel --progress "unzip -q {}"
```

It will spawn as many processes as there are cores on your machine and unzip each file. See [`parallel examples`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html).